# How do I print out a block of repeating numbers in a rectangle shape?

Tags: javascript, loops, integer

I am trying to repeat an exercise I learned a while ago in C++.  It has been a few years since I last built a function like this.  I would like to write this in JavaScript.

I am trying to write a program, that in ONE loop, it prints this to the screen/console/document:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
```

The code I have so far isn't working at all, I know I am doing something wrong.

```
function generate(){  
  for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    console.log( i + i + i + i +i +"<br>");
  }
}
```

It gives me an output of this:

```
0
5
10
15
20
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me out?  Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question.  It appears my mind is tired and making dumb mistakes haha.

The answer is:

```
function generate(){
var i = 1;
while (i < 6){
    console.log( i, i, i, i, i + '<br>');
  i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the line:

```
console.log( i + i + i + i +i +"<br>");
```

sums the values of `i` instead of concatenating. Starting with an empty string forces concatenation instead of addition:

```
console.log("" + i + i + i + i +i +"<br>");
```

Comment: It has been a long day of learning haha.  What a deerrrrr mistake.  Thank you.